# Dynamically created controls and the ASP.NET page lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, updatepanel, page-lifecycle

I'm working on an ASP.NET project in which the vast majority of the forms are generated dynamically at run time (form definitions are stored in a DB for customizability).  Therefore, I have to dynamically create and add my controls to the Page every time OnLoad fires, regardless of IsPostBack.  This has been working just fine and .NET takes care of managing ViewState for these controls.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    RenderDynamicControls()
}

private void RenderDynamicControls()
{
    //1. call service layer to retrieve form definition
    //2. create and add controls to page container
}
```

I have a new requirement in which if a user clicks on a given button (this button is created at design time) the page should be re-rendered in a slightly different way.  So in addition to the code that executes in OnLoad (i.e. RenderDynamicControls()), I have this code:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RenderDynamicControlsALittleDifferently() 
}

private void RenderDynamicControlsALittleDifferently()
{
    //1. clear all controls from the page container added in RenderDynamicControls()

    //2. call service layer to retrieve form definition

    //3. create and add controls to page container
}
```

My question is, is this really the only way to accomplish what I'm after?  It seems beyond hacky to effectively render the form twice simply to respond to a button click.  I gather from my research that this is simply how the page-lifecycle works in ASP.NET: Namely, that OnLoad must fire on every Postback before child events are invoked.  Still, it's worthwhile to check with the SO community before having to drink the kool-aid.

On a related note, once I get this feature completed, I'm planning on throwing an UpdatePanel on the page to perform the page updates via Ajax.  Any code/advice that make that transition easier would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to ASP.NET. Prepare for all logic to be thrown out the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Dirk to Dirk :-)

What do you mean with RenderDynamicControls? Create and set controls? If this is your intention not ASP.NET is managing your ViewState, but you do. If you fill the controls on every load, you always overwrite the existing ViewState!

If you want to use the ViewState, create your controls in the pages init event and fill them in the load event, but only if the request isn’t a postback. This is necessary, because ASP.NET recreates the ViewState between init and load. And this is also the reason for the two “rendering cycles” you describe. You need the first control creation cycle because ASP.NET can’t restore the ViewState without a proper control set and ASP.NET can’t react proper on your response without it.

Back to your code: In general your RenderDynamicControlsALittleDifferently wouldn’t work - because you create your controls too late in the pages life cycle and you would damage the ViewState by inserting new objects to the control collection. In a similar situation I solved this problem by a redirecting the page to itself (Response.Redirect). In this case RenderDynamicControls would do the job, based on a “little differently situation” after you change your internal state.