# Dynamic required validator and textboxes not firing inside panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a problem with validation. I created a dynamic textboxes with corresponding dynamic numeric validator but it's not firing.... 
Here is my code

code behind `on_load`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For i = 0 To AssetByDimension(oVal).Rows.Count - 1

        Dim lt As New Literal()
        Dim label As New Label()
        Dim count As Integer = pnlDimension.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count

        label.Text = "<b>" + AssetByDimension(oVal).Rows(i)("Dimension_Type") + " (" + AssetByDimension(oVal).Rows(i)("Unit_Of_Measure_Code") + "): </b>"
        pnlDimension.Controls.Add(label)

        Dim textbox As New TextBox()

        count = pnlDimension.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count

        textbox.ID = "txtDimension" & i
        pnlDimension.Controls.Add(textbox)

        Dim vdr As New RegularExpressionValidator

        vdr.ControlToValidate = "txtDimension" & i
        vdr.ValidationExpression = "\d+"
        vdr.ErrorMessage = "Numbers only"
        vdr.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        vdr.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        vdr.SetFocusOnError = True
        pnlDimension.Controls.Add(vdr)
        lt.Text = "<br /><br />"
        pnlDimension.Controls.Add(lt)


    Next
End Sub
```

and here's the button event handler

```
Protected Sub btnSaveDim_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

if Page.isvalid then
Response.Redirect("AddAsset.aspx")
else
      'do nothing...
end



End Sub
```

What I have tried:

I tried to use `Page.isValid` but is not working...

Hoping for your kind

Comment: Does it work if you type `abc` in the TextBox?

Comment: nope it doesn't validate...

Comment: [Seems relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809868/1188513)

Comment: How can you implement Viewstate inside my source  code?